# SharePoint Online - People picker not showing suggestions

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, sitepages, auto-populate

I am on SP Online environment and have seen 2 modes of people picker.

The first mode which seems to be the default OOTB(usually for newform.aspx) is to have the predictive text with auto suggestions.Refer to image below
[image]

The second mode, which seems to be for backward compatibility is the one where the user field shows you buttons for verify and for the address book.This happens when i add the people picker column to a page/sitepage. Refer to image.
[image]

Is there way to add the first mode(auto suggestion people picker) to a page/sitepage.

Please suggest. 
Thanks

Comment: I have had the same issue when I use custom Form for the list. Are you using Custom Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular.js and jQuery with REST call to auto complete people picker column.

More information, you can refer to:
[Auto-Complete People Picker In SharePoint Using Angular And jQuery](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/auto-complete-people-picker-in-sharepoint-using-angular-and-jquery/)

Another blog for your reference:
[SHAREPOINT 2013 CLIENT PEOPLE PICKER](https://blogs.ibs.com/2016/05/13/sharepoint-2013-client-people-picker/)